# The same bibliography with different sorting

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, sorting

**Attention: I have an answer and will publish it soon. But perhaps other have a different (or the same) solution, so I'm giving you the chance to show it first.**

How to output a bibliography with biblatex/biber more than once but with different sorting schemes?

The example where one should get the sorting implied from the titles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{herrmann}\cite{shore}\cite{aksin}

\printbibliography[title=Unsorted]

\printbibliography[title=Alphabetic]

\printbibliography[title=By year]

\end{document}
```

(The question was triggered by a speak about nmbib at tug2015).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about using `\newrefcontext` before each `\printbibliography` (apart the first which is under the context of the default sorting option of `biblatex`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{herrmann}\cite{shore}\cite{aksin}


\printbibliography[title=Unsorted]

\newrefcontext[sorting=nty]
\printbibliography[title=Alphabetic]

\newrefcontext[sorting=ynt]
\printbibliography[title=By year]

\end{document}
```

Obviously one should not use a numeric citation scheme with this.

[image]

Comment: That's my solution too. And you didn't fall into the trap to try to repeat the cite commands (the documentation is misleading in this respect imho and I added a comment at the biblatex tracker https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/331).