# Biblatex - Citation order different from Reference order

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, sorting

I am using `biblatex` with `biber` option. Is there a way to use the `ieee` style with citation being number in brackets, ordered by order of appearance but to have the references displayed with `\printbibliography` ordered alphabetically (e.g., by author name).

It would mean that in the section **reference**, entries are not sorted according to their citation number but according to another criterion.

The following MWE I would like the number in Alphabetic to be `[3] [2] [1]` so that each reference has only one number. E.g., currently the *Candy* Reference gets number `[1]` by order of appearance but then gets number `[3]` in Alphabetical order.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{biblatex-ieee.bib}
    @book{IEEEexample:bookwitheditor,
      editor        = "J. C. Candy and G. C. Temes",
      title         = "Oversampling Delta-Sigma Data Converters Theory,
                       Design and Simulation",
      publisher     = "{IEEE} Press.",
      location      = "New York",
      year          = "1992"
    }
    @inbook{IEEEexample:incollectionwithseries,
      author        = "J. B. Anderson and K. Tepe",
      title         = "Properties of the Tailbiting {BCJR} Decoder",
      booktitle     = "Codes, Systems and Graphical Models",
      series        = "{IMA} Volumes in Mathematics and Its Applications",
      publisher     = "Springer-Verlag",
      location      = "New York",
      year          = "2000"  
    }   
    @book{IEEEexample:inbookpagesnote,
      author        = "B. K. Bul",
      title         = "Theory Principles and Design of Magnetic Circuits",
      publisher     = "Energia Press",
      loction       = "Moscow",
      year          = "1964",
      pages         = "464",
      note          = "(in Russian)"
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{biblatex-ieee.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{IEEEexample:bookwitheditor}\cite{IEEEexample:inbookpagesnote}\cite{IEEEexample:incollectionwithseries}

\printbibliography[title=Unsorted]

\newrefcontext[sorting=nty]
\printbibliography[title=Alphabetic]

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: I don't know if ieee style does anything special but you should be able to do this with `sorting=none` as the global sorting option and then `\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]` before your `\printbibliography` to sort the references by, for example, the `nyt` sorting scheme.

Comment: It almost works but it changes the citation number for the **Reference** Section, similarly to what is presented [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258978/the-same-bibliography-with-different-sorting). Ideally I would like the citation number to stay by order of appearance (they will not be ordered in the Ref section).

Comment: Ok, can you please add a MWE to the question so we can see what you are doing?

Comment: With a numeric style like this, you can't really have `Candy` with the same number in both lists since the numbers are sequential and the sorting is different. It would be a strange reference list with the numbers in a random order.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think it is also strange that within the text `[1]` refers to _Candy_ but not in the reference section... That ends up being quite confusing. And with the `backref` option, it would not be too problematic to have numbers in the Reference section not in the sequential order. I will use another style, but I like the `ieee numeric` one.

Comment: That's correct because the citations and the "Unsorted" occur in the same reference context (sorting=none). The second bibliography occurs in a different reference context (sorting=nty). If you put a cite command in that reference context, it will be correct for that context.